# Ember-CLI, cannot register a service

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to register a "session" service from my session initializer.

**/services/session.js**

```
/* Imports */
import Ember from 'ember';

/* Session */
var Service =  Ember.Object.extend({
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log('Hello From Session Service');      
    }
});

/* Exports */
export default Service;
```

/initializers/session.js

```
/* Session Initializers */
var Initializer = {
    name: 'Session',
    initialize: function(Container, App) {

        App.register('service:session', App.Session);
        // This line doesn't work. See error below.

        App.inject('route', 'Session', 'service:session'); 
        // This works, I can access Session from my routes.
        App.inject('controller', 'Session', 'service:session');
        // This works, I can access Session from my 

    }
};

/* Export */
export default Initaializer;
```

**Error:** Uncaught TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `service:session`

Can I not register a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need to register the service, the resolver will look it up for you. I’d adjust things to look like this:

**app/services/session.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log('Hello From Session Service');      
  }
});
```

**app/initializers/session-service.js:**

```
export default {
  name: 'session-service',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    app.inject('route', 'session', 'service:session');
    app.inject('controller', 'session', 'service:session');
  }
};
```

This is pretty much exactly what you get when using `ember generate service session`.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I wanted to access this service from another service it had to be registered first. Is this not the case?

Comment: I'm successfully initializing services with the generator like this (no register), but the services are not accessible from each other, even after I add 'after'